# Grunt doesn't look for node_modules in parent directory? like node does

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, node-modules

I keep all my `node_modules` in the parent directory one level above the main project. Which works fine with node. But it seems grunt needs `node_modules` in the project directory.

Is there a way to get grunt to look in all parent directories to load whatever modules it needs?

http://runnable.com/U-xEnRK8Dhtr-eNY/output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this isn't possible and probably wouldn't be in the future either.

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/696#issuecomment-21634036